# Having trouble with int list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find all three digit armstrong numbers in python.
My script for this is

```
import re
a=[x for x in range(100, 1000)]
m = [int(e) for e in re.search((a),",")]
print(m)
z=((m[0]^len(m))+(m[1]^len(m))+(m[2]^len(m)))==m
print(z)
```

When i try to run this code it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ppc1-1 (2).py", line 3, in <module>
    m = [int(e) for e in re.search((a),",")]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 289, in _compile
    p, loc = _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

My objective is to find all three digit armstrong numbers.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line?
`m = [int(e) for e in re.search((a),",")]`

Comment: i was trying to get a single number out of the list.

Comment: >>> a = [x for x in range(100, 1000)]
>>> len(a)
900
>>> for i in a:
...     if int(i/100)**3 + int(i%100/10)**3 + int(i%10)**3 == i:
...             print (i)

Comment: what does len(a) 900 mean ?

Comment: @Mendjargal see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the armstong number in the following way.

**The review of your code**:

1)'^' does not mean exponent in python '**' operator is the exponent.

2) How do you expect to iterate over all the three digit numbers without using a loop?

```
a=[x for x in range(100, 1000)]

for i in a:
    m=list(map(int, str(i)))
    length=len(m)

    z=((m[0]**length)+(m[1]**length)+(m[2]**length))
    if z==i:
        print("The armstong number is",i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer to your issue:

```
  a = [x for x in range(100, 1000)]
  for i in range(0, len(a)):
    digits = [int(x) for x in str(a[i])]
    if (digits[0]**3 + digits[1]**3 + digits[2]**3) == a[i]:
        print a[i]
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This for only to find the three-digit Armstrong numbers in python.

```
import re
length = 3
arm = [e for e in range(100, 1000) if e == ((e/100)%10)**length + ((e/10)%10)**length + (e%10)**length]
print arm
```